# Content box floats out of Container div if there is a lot of text or other items

Tags: css, html

Edit:
This is currenty kinda resolved, Instead of struggling with the problem, I started making a new one.

I've got a problem, now it's that when I add content to the Content div on my site, for example a 100% height iframe, it makes the Content div expand and floats out of the Conatiner div.
So the css code is this..

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body{background-image:url('/media/Background.png');}
#Container{
position:relative; 
width: 900px;  
min-height:200px; 
margin: 0px auto 0 auto;  
text-align: left;  
padding-left: 1px;  
cursor: de; 
border-left: 1px solid #000001;
border-right: 1px solid #000001;
border-top: 1px solid #000001;

background-color:#C1E9FF; 
overflow:inherit;
}
#LogoContainer{
position:absolute; 
background-image:url('/media/Logo.png'); 
border-right-width:1px; 
border-bottom-width:1px; 
border-right-color:rgb(0,0,1); 
border-bottom-color:rgb(0,0,1); 
border-right-style:solid; 
border-bottom-style:solid; 
width:400px; 
height:50px; 
}
#LikeBar{
position:absolute;
border-bottom-width:1px; 
border-bottom-color:rgb(0,0,1); 
border-bottom-style:solid; 
width:500px; 
height:50px;  
left:400px;
}
#ButtonHome{
position:absolute; 
background-image:url('/media/Bt.png'); 
width:100px; 
height:30px;  
top:50px; 
z-index:1;
}
#ButtonVideo{
position:absolute; 
background-image:url('/media/Bt.png'); 
width:100px; 
height:30px; 
left:105; 
top:50px; 
z-index:1;
}
#ButtonSpeedtest{
position:absolute; 
background-image:url('/media/Bt.png'); 
width:100px; 
height:30px; 
left:210; 
top:50px; 
z-index:1;
}
#ButtonYVideos{
position:absolute; 
background-image:url('/media/Bt.png'); 
width:100px; 
height:30px; 
left:315; 
top:50px; 
z-index:1;
}
#YouTubeBox{
position:absolute; 
background-image:url('/media/Box.png'); 
width:100px; 
height:30; 
left:10px; 
text-align:center;
}
#TwitterBox{
position:absolute; 
background-image:url('/media/Box.png'); 
width:100px; 
height:30; 
left:110px; 
text-align:center;
}
#FaceBookBox{
position:absolute; 
background-image:url('/media/Box.png'); 
width:100px; 
height:30; 
left:210px; 
text-align:center;
}
#Content{
position:relative;  
top:90px; 
width:780px; 
min-height:80%; 
border-top:1px solid #000001; 
}
#Footer{
position:relative; 
border-top-width:1px; 
border-top-color:rgb(0,0,1); 
border-bottom: 1px solid #000001;
border-top-style:solid; 
width:900px; 
bottom:0px; 
z-index:1; 
text-align:center; 
}
#AdFooter{
position:relative; 
width:728px;  
height:100px; 
margin: 0px auto 0 auto;  
border-left: 1px solid #000001;
border-right: 1px solid #000001;
}
#AdSidebar{
position:absolute; 
width:120px;  
height:600px; 
left:780px;
top:50px;
border-left: 1px solid #000001;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000001;
}
p{line-height: 1px;}
```

And the Current html code, without the content that is not related to the error.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Faulty css</title>
<link href="ThemeV1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="Container"> <!-- Start Container -->
<div id="LogoContainer">
</div>
<div id="LikeBar">
<p class="DivT">
</p>
</div>
<!-- Menu Controls -->
<a href="/"><div id="ButtonHome"><center><p>Home</p></center></div></a>
<!-- <a href="/blog"><div id="ButtonVideo"><center><p>Blog</p></center></div></a> -->
<a href="/Speedtest.html"><div id="ButtonSpeedtest"><center><p>SpeedTest</p></center></div></a> 
<a href="/videos.html"><div id="ButtonVideo"><center><p>Videos</p></center></div></a>
<!-- WEBSITE CONTENT -->
<div id="Content">
<iframe src="about:blank" width="100%" height="100%" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
<!-- END WEBSITE CONTENT -->
<!-- Footer -->
<div id="Footer">
<p>Test</p>
<th>
</div>
<!-- End Footer -->
<div id="AdFooter">
</div>
<div id="AdSidebar">
</div>
</div> <!-- End Container -->
</body>
</html>
```

My guess for why this is caused, is that the footer is locked, and doesn't move when the content is getting bigger.
And that I don't wanna do is to recode everything cause this was the first theme I created, but it works, but with the bug on footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `p` within your `#Footer`. You have `line-height: 1px`, which is forcing that text up out of the footer. You should probably be either padding the `#Footer p` or forcing a much larger `line-height`. I'd also set a static height or some sort of padding on the footer itself.

Comment: I tried it, but the footer is still overlayed cause of the content, so the footer doesn't change the height, and the P never was forcing out of the footer.

Comment: You should really try one of the CSS sticky footer solutions.